# Apache rotatelogs failed unexpectedly

Tags: apache

I have a problem with my local Apache.
When I start the service, the error.log of my Apache is full of:

> piped log program 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/bin/rotatelogs.exe C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/access-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400 +120' failed unexpectedly
>
> "C:\Program" is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Does anyone know what the problem is?
I suppose the reason is the space-character in the path.
My httpd.conf looks like this:

```
CustomLog "|C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/bin/rotatelogs.exe C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/access-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400 +120" common
ErrorLog "|C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/bin/rotatelogs.exe C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/error-%Y-%m-%d.log 86400 +120"
```

As I write it in quote signs, I thought the blanks would be no problem.
Can anyone help here?

I use Apache 2.2.22

Comment: Does it work if you set a var (like `APACHE_HOME=C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2`) and run it this way ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Did try, made no difference :(

Answer (score 0):

The path contains space. In this case should be quoted:

```
'C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/bin/rotatelogs.exe'
```

Full sample:

```
ErrorLog "|'C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/bin/rotatelogs.exe' 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/error-%Y-%m-%d.log' 86400 +120"
```

Additionally, the rotatelog path can be referred by relative path:

```
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/error-%Y-%m-%d.log' 86400 +120"
```